# How do I install JDK7 (Java 7) on Mac OS X 10.7.3?

Tags: java, macos, java-7

What is the link to install JDK7 (Java 7) on Mac OS X 10.7.3?

What version does it install?

Where does it install on my box?

How do I use it?

Comment: Did you try to google it? [http://openjdk.java.net/projects/macosx-port/](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/macosx-port/). Do you look for some specific vendor JDK?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u4-downloads-1591156.html

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u4-downloads-1591156.html

Comment: Thanks, but as my answer mentions, there is a crucial step of selecting JDK7 as your default JDK in `Java Preferences` before it will be used on the command line by default.

Comment: @HeathBorders - which is in the readme you open from the installer

Comment: I skipped over that step during my install and I resorted to googling to find the answer. I figured I'd put my answers here to help others.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Download Java SE 7u4 from Oracle.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u4-downloads-1591156.html) (This is 64-bit only)

This installs to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk`.

However, when you run `java -version` it will still output `1.6` or some other old version.  [Follow the readme directions below:](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-for-mac-readme-1564562.html)

Open `Java Preferences` in `/Applications/Utilities`. Drag `Java SE 7` to the top. It will now be your default JVM. Run `java -version` again, and you should see something like:

```
java version "1.7.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-bxx)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b17, mixed mode)
```

Once this is complete, a new install of Eclipse should select JDK7 by default.  Otherwise:

1. go to `Eclipse`->`Preferences...`->`Java`->`Installed JREs`
2. click `Add...`
3. Select `Standard VM`
4. paste `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home` into `JRE home`
5. Change the `JRE name` to something useful like `Java SE 7`
6. Click `Finish`
7. Check the checkbox next to your newly created JRE.

Comment: I followed the README from the installer to set the new JDK to be my preferred version, but `/usr/bin/java` is still pointing at Apple's `1.6.0_31` version in `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents`

Comment: I also don't have Java Preferences any more after installing. I never saw a "readme" with the installer. Still looking. I think it's a symbolic link to blame, but it seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: how do you do this in a clean way now that Apple has removed "Java Preferences"

I've installed the JDK 7u10 from Oracle, I've set my JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)

but all my tools /usr/bin/java, etc. still point to the old Apple's JDK folder.

It's weird that I do which java and it shows the right path, but when I execute it, it still will execute the old one (1.6 from apple)

something must be overriding the $PATH, *sigh*

Comment: Yes, something is probably overriding your path because `/usr/libexec/java_home` is always supposed to point to the latest JRE.

Comment: Doesn't work.  I run the package installer and it says "Installation Successful" but I cannot find JDK 7 anywhere.  There is no `Java Preferences` application, and nothing in the filesystem at `Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk`.

Comment: Nevermind, I found the issue. I was trying to install the Java 7 package off of java.com (~50MB). When I went and got the one from Oracle (~150MB), that one installed correctly. Still no 'Java Preferences' app though.

Comment: Latest release URL is http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u17-b02/jdk-7u17-macosx-x64.dmg

Comment: I can confirm that @aroth is correct, it looks like Oracle has killed Java Preferences, which makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 7):

Make sure that you aren't setting JAVA_HOME in your .bash_profile, otherwise this may prevent java -version from returning the desired result.

Comment: I had precisely this issue. `JAVA_HOME` was being set to `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Home` and `java -version` was returning `1.6.0_31` rather than `1.7.0_04`. Clearing `JAVA_HOME` fixed this for me. It was very strange. 2 Terminal windows were returning different results for `/usr/bin/java -version`, depending on the value of `JAVA_HOME`

Answer (score -5):

You just download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), install it where you like, and include it in your path or select that JDK in your IDE

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to know how to get it to run by default from the command line.  After installation, `java -version` still points to 1.6

Comment: Unless you make sure your new installed JDK comes first in your path, as you have already discovered

Comment: read the readme on the installer