# mac replace java 6 with java 7 in /usr/bin/java

Tags: java, macos, installation

1. when I enter "whereis java" in terminal is says: /usr/bin/java
   when I enter "java -version" it says "1.6.0_43" ...
2. when I open the Java control panel in system preference, the only version that i can see is Java 1.7.0_17 with the location at "/Library/Internet Plug-ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java". I don't have a "Java preference" panel that provides me to choose which version to use with some priority.

It is obvious that when internet browser is using, java 7 will be used and while I'm compiling Java in terminal Java 6 is used. But how could I get rid of Java 6? Is there a way that I could install Java 7 under /usr/bin/java?

BTW, I am not sure how to use the .profile file. Could i modify this file so that when I am in the terminal i can still use java 7?

Comment: According to [this article](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57423014-263/how-to-install-and-uninstall-java-7-for-os-x/), it looks like Apple has dropped updates past Java 6. I've been out of the OS X world for a couple of years now, so I'm not sure why you have a Java 7 browser plugin. [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350867/how-do-i-install-jdk7-java-7-on-mac-os-x-10-7-3) looks to ask pretty much your question, and the accepted answer may help. I'm willing to bet the answer is not out of date, given the comments on the answer as recent as Feb of this year.

Comment: great. thanks i've solved this problem.

Comment: Was my comment essentially the solution? If so I can post it as an answer, and you can accept it to indicate to others how your problem was solved. If not, you can answer yourself as to what you did and accept it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Download Java SE 7u4 from Oracle.

Install it.

This version is different from the version downloaded while browsing the website.

It is really wired though...

Answer (score -1):

In the meantime version 7u4 is no longer current and full of security holes!

My solution (which I got from the link provided in the comments) was to install the current Version of Java and start `/Applications/Utilities/Java-Settings` which displays the currently installed Java versions and allows to set the default version. Drag the current version to the top. Then `/usr/bin/java` pointed to the right version.